# Adding Bootstrap Fields based on drop-down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a drop-down where I'm listing the number of users based on a number selection. So let's say that they pick '7' users from the list, it will show two extra text boxes and so on.

Here is the code:

```js
 <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $('select[name=totalUsers]').change(function () {
  $('.six').hide();
  $('.seven').hide();
  $('.eight').hide();
  $('.nine').hide();
  $('.ten').hide();
   
  $("select[name=totalUsers] option:selected").each(function () {
   var value = $(this).val();
   if(value == "six") {
    $('.six').show();
   
   } else if(value == "seven") {
    $('.seven').show();
   
   } else if(value == "eight") {
    $('.eight').show();
   
   } else if(value == "nine") {
    $('.nine').show();

   } else if(value == "tenUsers") {
    $('.ten').show();
   }
  });
   });
  });
 </script>
```

```html
<div class="container">
<form id="myform" data-toggle="validator">
  <fieldset>

 <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="totalUsers" class="col-lg-10 col-form-label">Number of Attendees:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="totalUsers">
   <option value="five" selected>5</option>
   <option value="six">6</option>
   <option value="seven">7</option>
   <option value="eight">8</option>
   <option value="nine">9</option>
   <option value="ten">10</option>
    </select><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group row one">
   <label for="oneUser" class="col-lg-10 col-form-label">Names of Attendees:</label><input class="form-control" name="oneUser" type="text" id="oneUser" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." placeholder="Ex: John Smith" required/><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row two">
   <input class="form-control" name="twoUsers" type="text" id="twoUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name."required/><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row three">
   <input class="form-control" name="threeUsers" type="text" id="threeUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row four">
   <input class="form-control" name="fourUsers" type="text" id="fourUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row five">
   <input class="form-control" name="fiveUsers" type="text" id="fiveUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row six">
   <input class="form-control" name="sixUsers" type="text" id="sixUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row seven">
   <input class="form-control" name="sevenUsers" type="text" id="sevenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row eight">
   <input class="form-control" name="eightUsers" type="text" id="eightUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row nine">
   <input class="form-control" name="nineUsers" type="text" id="nineUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group row ten">
   <input class="form-control" name="tenUsers" type="text" id="tenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
  
 <div class="form-group row col-lg-8">
  <button type="submit" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" name="cancelbutton" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" onclick="window.location.href=''">Cancel</button>
 </div>
```

I have my jQuery set to where it's supposed to show/hide the text fields based on the number selection but it's not working for me - All help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first thing I noticed is the incorrect jquery selector. You could select an element by its ID with **$("#ID")** .

The .each is not necessary also, you could access the value property of the selected object via **$("#ID").val()** .

It looks more appropriate to use **switch case** instead of multiple If statements as you have many conditions there.

**Do run the snippet,** thanks! edit: Placed Csaba's switch case script, it's neater!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Moved this to the top, this would hide the elements when the page is ready
  $('.six').hide();
  $('.seven').hide();
  $('.eight').hide();
  $('.nine').hide();
  $('.ten').hide();

  /* $('select[name=totalUsers]') is incorrect for this
example because the totalUsers is the ID. The correct way of selecting through ID is $("#totalUsers")*/
  $("#totalUsers").change(function() {

    // Hide them again, because some of them are shown at the end
    $('.six').hide();
    $('.seven').hide();
    $('.eight').hide();
    $('.nine').hide();
    $('.ten').hide();

    // Loop is not necessary, just get the value from the select field.
    var selectValue = $(this).val();

    // Use switch for cleaner code
    switch (selectValue) {
        case "ten":
          $('.ten').show();
        case "nine":
          $('.nine').show();
        case "eight":
          $('.eight').show()
        case "seven":
          $('.seven').show();
        case "six":
          $('.six').show();
        case "five":
          $('.five').show();
      }
    
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

select,
input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form id="myform" data-toggle="validator">
    <fieldset>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="totalUsers" class="col-lg-10 col-form-label">Number of Attendees:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="totalUsers">
          <option value="five" selected>5</option>
          <option value="six">6</option>
          <option value="seven">7</option>
          <option value="eight">8</option>
          <option value="nine">9</option>
          <option value="ten">10</option>
        </select>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row one">
        <label for="oneUser" class="col-lg-10 col-form-label">Names of Attendees:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="oneUser" type="text" id="oneUser" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." placeholder="Ex: John Smith" required/>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row two">
        <input placeholder="Two" class="form-control" name="twoUsers" type="text" id="twoUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>

        <div class="form-group row three">
          <input placeholder="Three" class="form-control" name="threeUsers" type="text" id="threeUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row four">
          <input placeholder="Four" class="form-control" name="fourUsers" type="text" id="fourUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row five">
          <input placeholder="Five" class="form-control" name="fiveUsers" type="text" id="fiveUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row six">
          <input placeholder="Six" class="form-control" name="sixUsers" type="text" id="sixUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row seven">
          <input placeholder="Seven" class="form-control" name="sevenUsers" type="text" id="sevenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row eight">
          <input placeholder="Eight" class="form-control" name="eightUsers" type="text" id="eightUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row nine">
          <input placeholder="Nine" class="form-control" name="nineUsers" type="text" id="nineUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row ten">
          <input placeholder="Ten" class="form-control" name="tenUsers" type="text" id="tenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row col-lg-8">
          <button type="submit" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" name="cancelbutton" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" onclick="window.location.href=''">Cancel</button>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @Jerdine Sabio! I'll look into the issue where when you change it to six, seven, etc.. it just replaces the text and doesn't add a textbox.

Comment: Hi @SaintLouisEvents, actually, it doesn't replace the text. It hides all the other specified divs and just shows the matching class on switch statement.

Do you need to show a number of input fields depending on the select value?

Comment: Yup, that is correct @Jerdine, So let's say that I select '5' - I'd like to show 5 input fields,
6 = 6 input fields, etc.. and then when a user switches back to 5 it's back to 5 only.

I do appreciate all the help with this.

Comment: Hi @SaintLouisEvents I revised the code to match the behavior you want. There's a better way to write the hiding and showing though but to be simple; I specified all the divs I want to show depending on the case.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still new to jQuery and JavaScript so my attempt wasn't working too well - This works like a charm +1

Comment: @JerdineSabio check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Jerdine Sabio's answer works but if you want to write it in a more elegant way then you can do this in your `switch` statement:
Instead of:

```
// Use switch for cleaner code
    switch (selectValue) {
      case "five":
        $('.five').show();
      case "six":
        $('.five').show();
        $('.six').show();
        break;
      case "seven":
        $('.five').show();
        $('.six').show();
        $('.seven').show();
        break;
      case "eight":
        $('.five').show();
        $('.six').show();
        $('.seven').show();
        $('.eight').show();
        break;
      case "nine":
        $('.five').show();
        $('.six').show();
        $('.seven').show();
        $('.eight').show();
        $('.nine').show();
        break;
      case "ten":
        $('.five').show();
        $('.six').show();
        $('.seven').show();
        $('.eight').show();
        $('.nine').show();
        $('.ten').show();
        break;
    }
```

Leave out breaks and use fall-through:

```
switch (value) {
    case "ten":
        $('.ten').show();
    case "nine":
        $('.nine').show();
    case "eight":
        $('.eight').show()
    case "seven":
        $('.seven').show();
    case "six":
        $('.six').show();
    case "five":
        $('.five').show();
}
```

This means that if you select `ten` then the `switch` statement will execute all code which is under the case for `ten`.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents, ah there you go, a better way to write it.

Comment: *included this snippet in the answer*

Comment: Thanks for the improvement guys!